# Java - Add to DOM XML File

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have the following XML, I would like to add another "product" to the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Computer</name>
        <code>PC1003</code>
        <description>Basic Computer</description>
        <price>399.99</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Monitor</name>
        <code>MN1003</code>
        <description>LCD Monitor</description>
        <price>99.99</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Printer</name>
        <code>PR1003x</code>
        <description>Inkjet Printer</description>
        <price>54.23</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
        // Variables
        File file = new File("db_products.xml"); // set xml to parse

        // Create builders
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file); // load xml file
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        doc.createElement("product");
```

I don't really care where the new "product" section is added. I just can't seem to grasp what is the difference between a node and an element. I'm assuming the correct way to add a new "product" section would be to add a child to "products" and then add children (name,code,etc.) to "product".

Any help on how to easily do this, or a link to a simple tutorial would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is retrieve the `products` element first and then call the `appendChild` on that element. Something like this:

```
Element productElement = doc.createElement("product");
productElement.setAttribute("name", "value");
//Other name value pairs...

//Append the products element to the right spot.
Element productsElement = (Element) doc.getElementByTagName("products").item(0);
productsElement.appendChild(productElement);

//Convert doc to xml string
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
String xmlAsString = writer.toString();
```

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was looking for, thanks! One problem I have that's not a huge deal, but it places everything on one line, is there a way to format the output?

Comment: I've never had that problem before @WillSharp, so I'm not sure what to tell you. I can't remember whether I've never experienced that and it never mattered enough for me to notice, or if that hasn't happened to me at all. Maybe ask another question and someone will have some insight :)